# Equivalence of definitions of Gaussian Measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Wikipedia's article on Gaussian measures notes this as the definition of Gaussian measures:
$\gamma_{\mu, \sigma^{2}}^{n} (A) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2}}^{n}} \int_{A} \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^{2}} \| x - \mu \|_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}^{2} \right) \, \mathrm{d} \lambda^{n} (x).$
I haven't been able to find this definition anywhere else, including the book by Bogachev.

In Bogachev's book, they mention that the density of the measure is given by:
$x \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^n \det K}} \exp{\{-\frac{1}{2}<K^{-1} (x - a), x - a> \}}$, where $K$ is the covariance.

My first question is:
Is the wikipedia definition accurate? If it is, can someone give me a reference to a published book or lectures notes for a class or some reference that has the same definition?

My second question:
How are these definitions the same? Perhaps I don't understand densities of measures well, but aren't the expressions supposed to be exactly the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "Wikipedia" definition is for the special case where the covariance matrix is $\sigma^2 I$.  In that case they are equivalent.  A measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^n$ has density $\rho$ with respect to Lebesgue measure $\lambda^n$ iff 
$\mu(A) = \int_A \rho(x) \; d\lambda^n(x)$ for all Lebesgue measurable sets $A$.